# sql count the date less than current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where user input a target date, and then I want to output the count of names where their associated target date is greater than current date. 
I tried but I'm getting the same results

below is the code

```
$select1_query = "
SELECT ACCOUNT_NAME
     , COUNT(NCI_NUMBER)
     , COUNT(CURDATE()>TARGET_DATE) 
  FROM sim_tracker 
 WHERE NCI_STATUS != 'Closed' 
 GROUP 
    BY ACCOUNT_NAME
";
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: remove`, COUNT(CURDATE()>TARGET_DATE) ` and add `AND CURDATE()<TARGET_DATE` to the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `count()`.  Use `sum()`:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NAME,
       COUNT(NCI_NUMBER),
       SUM(CURDATE() > TARGET_DATE) 
FROM sim_tracker 
WHERE NCI_STATUS <> 'Closed' 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NAME;
```

This works because MySQL treats booleans expressions as "1" for true and "0" for false in a numeric context.  `SUM()` then counts the number of "true" values.

`COUNT()` does not work, because `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  "true" and "false" are both non-`NULL`, so they both get counted.

Comment: Thank you Sir. That worked like a charm! thank you so much